# A sphere and a cylinder have equal volumes. Find h in terms of r

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

A sphere and a cylinder have equal volumes. The sphere has a radius 2r. The cylinder has radius r and height h. Find h in terms of r.

This came up in my maths paper today, anyone got any answers?

EDIT: Changed value of the radii so answers below are no longer correct

Comment: $\frac{4π(3r)^3}{3}=π(2r)^2h$ gives $h=9r$

Comment: Your edit makes the accepted answer wrong. That's going to seriously confuse anyone who comes across your question later. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume of sphere is $V_s=\frac{4}{3}\pi(3r)^3=36\pi r^3$ 
Volume of cylinder is $V_c=\pi(2r)^2h=4\pi r^2h$

Hence, equating the volumes, we get 
$$36\pi r^3=4\pi r^2h \implies h=9r$$

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks really helpful. What would it be now that I've changed it so that the cylinder has radius r and the sphere 2r?

Comment: @lucafsorrentino Replace $3r$ by $2r$ and $2r$ by $r$ accordingly. The answer will be $h=\frac{32}{3}r$. If my answer helps you, you can click the  green tick beside my answer and accept it.